# Powershell get list of all folders and files modified in the last 4 months in ascending order

Tags: list, powershell, file, sorting, directory

I've tried the following code to get a list of files and folders sorted by last modified date:

```
Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse -File -Path "E:\ES" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime.Date -lt (Get-Date).Date } | Sort CreationTime -Descending | Format-Table -Wrap
```

Can this code be edited such that the list of folders and files er limited to those modified in the last 4 months?

Thank you in advance! You guys have been so so helpful with answering all my previous questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, all you have to change are:

- the date to compare against (`(Get-Date).Date` gets you the todays date at midnight, `(Get-Date).AddMonths(-4).Date` gets you the date 4 months ago at midnight)
- the comparison operator: `-ge` will get you all dates greater or equal to the date of 4 months ago)
- the property you need: `LastWriteTime` is thedate the file was last modified. `CreationTime` can also be the date the file was copied to its final destination and is not necessarily the actual date the file was first created.

```
$refDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-4).Date  # 4 months ago at midnight

Get-ChildItem -Path "E:\ES" -Force -Recurse -File -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | 
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -ge $refDate } | 
Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending | 
Format-Table -Wrap
```

The above wil list only files. If you want Directories aswell just remove the `-File` switch.